# I can't scrape src image link with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I'm trying to scrape food images links from restaurants on the `Postmates`. For the example I'm trying on this restaurant: `https://postmates.com/merchant/fruitive-washington-96807`

The `src` that has the image link, seems a little bit difficult for me to export it. I tried everything I knew, but with 0 results. Always I have a return like this: `[]` or a `list index out of range error` or `None type error` and generally errors.

The code of the page is this:

```
<div id="" class="e1tw3vxs2 css-aktk0j e1qfcze90">
  <div>
    <img alt="Spring Pesto from Fruitive. Order online." src="https://raster-static.postmates.com/? 
     url=https%3A%2F%2Fitems-static.postmates.com%2Fuploads%2Fmedia%2F7b289988-5d19-4cfc-80a6- ce88a7a05f41%2Foriginal.jpg%3Fv%3D63784935843&amp;quality=85&amp;w=320&amp;h=0&amp;mode=auto&amp;format=webp&amp;v=4" 
     class="css-1hyfx7x e1qfcze94">
    <div title="Spring Pesto from Fruitive. Order online." class="css-1ggm7mr e1qfcze91" 
    style="background-image: url(&quot;https://raster-static.postmates.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fitems- 
    static.postmates.com%2Fuploads%2Fmedia%2F7b289988-5d19-4cfc-80a6-ce88a7a05f41%2Foriginal.jpg%3Fv%3D63784935843&amp;quality=85&amp;w=320&amp;h=0&amp;mode=auto&amp;
    format=webp&amp;v=4&quot;); opacity: 1;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="css-f85l49 e1qfcze92"></div>
</div>
```

My code for the scrape was this:

```
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"}
page_code = requests.get('https://postmates.com/merchant/fruitive-washington-96807', headers = header)
soup = bs(page_code.content, 'html.parser')

page_code = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'css-135ydxp e1u06svg2'})
for i in page_code:
    all_element_products = i.find_all('div',{'class':'product-container css-1kry540 e1tw3vxs3'})
    for a_e_p in all_element_products:
        try:
            img_link = a_e_p.find_all('div', {'class':'e1tw3vxs2 css-aktk0j e1qfcze90'})
        except Exception as Err:
            print(Err)
            print()
            img_link = '-'
        print(img_link)
```

Anybody with a solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info you see on the page is rendered dynamically and the data is embedded in JSON format. You can use this example of how to load it using the `re`/`json` modules:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = "https://postmates.com/merchant/fruitive-washington-96807"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ({.*?});", html_doc).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for cat in data["cart"]["categories"]:
    for product in cat["products"]:
        # print only products with image:
        if "img" in product:
            print(
                "{:<30} {}".format(
                    product["name"], product["img"]["originalUrl"]
                )
            )
```

Prints:

```
Loaded Avocado Toast           https://items-static.postmates.com/uploads/media/a9f25be8-fd4a-4615-8f50-5f767d76ade9/original.jpg?v=63784935508
Pink Punch                     https://items-static.postmates.com/uploads/media/1db56bd1-9128-4ee6-837f-63c2db004494/original.jpg?v=63784935614
Tropical Bowl                  https://items-static.postmates.com/uploads/media/150f8376-ab6d-45e0-b21f-35c648f31814/original.jpg?v=63784935705
Beach Breeze                   https://items-static.postmates.com/uploads/media/c8bb194b-d12f-4684-a542-76c17310538f/original.jpg?v=63784935751
Spring Pesto                   https://items-static.postmates.com/uploads/media/7b289988-5d19-4cfc-80a6-ce88a7a05f41/original.jpg?v=63784935843
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot man! A question. What ```"{:<30} {}"``` means?

Comment: @bilakos It's just for string formatting. That means the first item (the product name) should be fixed with (30 characters `{:<30}`)